# String/text manipulation utility class

Tags: c++, performance, object-oriented, strings

I'd like to get some expert's view on this first piece of code especially in the area of

- performance - (e.g. avoidable copies)
- good practice (e.g. static members?)

The final goal is the provide some abstractions for text manipulation like cleansing, stop-word removal and tokenization. The code base should grow substantially in the future so a lot more string manipulation methods should be supported. I understand that this should be bundled in a library in the end, however, I'd like to get feedback on the general code style first.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class TextManipulator {
 public:
  static std::string replace(std::string &string, const std::string pattern,
                             const std::string toreplace) {
    return std::regex_replace(string, std::regex(pattern), toreplace);
  }

  static std::string toLowerCase(std::string &string) {
    std::locale loc;
    std::string res;
    for (auto elem : string) {
      res += std::tolower(elem, loc);
    }
    return res;
  }

  static std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &text,
                                        char seperator) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::size_t start = 0, end = 0;
    while ((end = text.find(seperator, start)) != std::string::npos) {
      std::string extr = text.substr(start, end - start);
      if (!extr.empty()) {
        tokens.push_back(extr);
      }
      start = end + 1;
    }
    tokens.push_back(text.substr(start));
    return tokens;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::ifstream input(
      "/example_docs/Pride_and_Prejudice.txt");
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << input.rdbuf();
  std::string text = buffer.str();

  text = TextManipulator::replace(text, "\r\n", " ");
  text = TextManipulator::replace(text, ",", "");
  text = TextManipulator::replace(text, ":", "");
  text = TextManipulator::replace(text, ".", "");
  text = TextManipulator::toLowerCase(text);
  std::vector<std::string> tokens = TextManipulator::split(text, ' ');

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Don't use a `class`

There is no need to create a `class` just to hold a collection of `static` functions. Instead, just declare the functions in the global namespace. If you want to avoid polluting the global namespace, consider putting them in a `namespace` instead, like so:

```
namespace TextManipulation {

std::string replace(...) {
    ...
};

...
}
```

## Don't write unnecessary trivial wrapper functions

There is no need to create `TextManipulator::replace()`, when all it does is call `std::regex_replace` with almost exactly the same arguments. Why not call `std::regex_replace()` directly instead?

The name `replace()` also hides the fact that `pattern` is a regular expression.

## Consider renaming `toLowerCase()` to `tolower()`

It's a bit annoying to have different naming conventions in one program, and since you already have `tolower()` for single characters, it would be very convenient to reuse that for whole strings as well. So:

```
std::string tolower(const std::string &str) {
    ...
}
```

Note: you forget to add `const` to the function parameter here, as well as for the first parameter of `replace()`, but you did it correctly for the other string parameters.

Answer (score -3):

Whenever possible, use [boost::string_ref](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) in your code, this will reduce the number of copy operations with `std::string`. Check the places where you have copy operations and replace them with `boost::string_ref` operations if possible.

Comment: There's `string_view` in c++17

Comment: Yes you are right if you are in standard 17 or higher